# Choosing right server setup before launching a website

Tags: laravel, performance, server, image-uploading, scalability

My current server configuration is:

```
US Central Servers (Michigan)
US West Servers (Arizona)
EU Netherlands (Amsterdam)
SINGLE PROCESSOR
Intel Xeon E3-1230 v6
4 Cores @ 3.5 GHz
16 GB RAM
2 x 240 480 GB SSD Primary Storage 2X Storage
1 TB SATA Backup Drive
5 TB Bandwidth
```

I am hosting laravel application. I have installed FFMPEG and FFMPROBE for image and video uploading. On every upload, jobs for making thumbs(images) or encoding videos are started.
Database is mysql. It is on the same server. I use mongoDB too on same server.
Is this a good setup? Will it be good for 10-50K users?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are we talking about concurrent users or what is the actual workload you're expecting (like _20 uploads per minute_)?

Comment: Let's say 20 uploads per minute.@Namoshek

Comment: Then, without being anywhere near an expert on this topic, I'll make the educated guess that this won't be even nearly enough power to encode that much videos. It most likely also depends on the length of the videos and the resolution.